# Why some GUI icons of some Qt applications in Kubuntu 20.04 look bad?

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, icons, display-resolution, qt

In Kubuntu 20.04 some Qt applications (Double Commander QT, SMPlayer, Apper) have icons that look bad.

Apper:

[image]

[image]

SMPlayer with Papirus Dark icons:

[image]

with Breeze icons:

[image]

and, like above, also the settings confirmation dialog:

[image]

DoubleCommander-qt:

[image]

[image]

Most other icons look fine (no default application is affected). I am not very surprised that Apper (a rather old app) is affected, but was not expecting SMPlayer to have a problem like that (which I have never seen in Xfce, Cinnamon, and  --I think-- on newer Plasma versions neither.

It doesn't seem related to the resolution of the laptop (1920x1080). Reducing that changes nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, this problem is caused by the global scale above 100% under Display Configuration.

As an alternative to increasing global scale, one can increase font size and/or also "Force font DPI", which for some reason also enlarges some GUI details, like the window buttons.